# efficient ways to check prime number in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

Here is my code, and pretty brute force. Seeking smarter solutions. I remember there are some theory in Number Theory to check whether a number is a prime number with high efficiency, but cannot find it out. Anyone have smarter ideas are appreciated.

```
def isPrimeNumber(self, num):
    i = 2
    while (i <= num / 2):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
        i = i + 1

    return True
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Where have you searched? Obvious optimizations are using the square root of `num` as a limit (inclusive), and skipping even numbers that are not 2.

Comment: @ReutSharabani, not sure if AKS algorithm is better efficiency? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test, I cannot find a Python implementation, let me know if you have one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Improve performance. And loop occur till `square root` of this number
You can try this:

```
import math
def isPrimeNumber(self, num):
    for i in range(2, sqrt(num)):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: not sure if AKS algorithm is better efficiency? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test, I cannot find a Python implementation, let me know if you have one. :)

Answer (score 1):

One huge and simple optimization you can do to your code is to stop looking for divisors when you reach the square root of your `num`.

Comment: thanks, not sure if AKS algorithm is better efficiency? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test, I cannot find a Python implementation, let me know if you have one. :)